# Are SharePoint Column / Field variations gone in SPO?

Tags: sharepoint, localization

For years I created columns in SP in the following way:

1. Fix browser accept-language header to default language of site
   (e.g. en-US)
2. Create column with an internal name
3. Rename column to default language name
4. Fix browser accept-language header to next language (e.g. de-DE)
5. Rename column to next language name

This worked and the translated names are still shown.

I now tried the same steps on 2 new sites on different tenants and it seems variants are not longer created: always all languages are changed.

**resx** files created by **Site settings** > **Export Translations** does not contain newly created fields / columns.

Was this feature removed?

If yes: what is the current way to create multilingual data-lists (one list filled by many users in different countries/languages)?

If no: has the way to translate fields / columns changed? Or is this a (temporal) bug in current SPO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multilingual user interface (MUI) works exactly the same way in SharePoint Online as on premise.  However your browser's Accept-language is not the only thing that governs the current UI language, your [profile language](http://blog.icefire.ca/post/sharepoint-online-language-settings-and-the-instant-toggle-trick) is another factor, and you have to wait for it to take effect.

When you change your language in order to enter the column names in a different language, check that at least some of the built-in UI, menus, edit link, etc, is in the new language.  Bits of it are cached and will take a long time to be in the right language, but as soon as some of it changes, you are good to edit those column names and any untranslated navigation while you are at it.

Comment: Yeah, profile language setting is / was initially set. The thingy about build-in translation was also considered: many components in modern design is filled via JS so I reloaded always the full page after change of Accept-Header.
The translation export did not contain the whole custom field/column ...
Did you check on a new Site or do you answered because "it should work that way"?

Comment: It is literally what I and my team do all day. I did check on a new site because if it ever changed it would have a huge impact on hundreds of customers.  Translation export is not reliable, unfortunately.  
If profile setting is set to a site or alternative language, then changing Accept-Header won't do anything.  You are right about JS, but certain elements like navigation are also stored in local storage or local indexed DB.  Column headers are not as persistent.

Comment: MS is definitly just changing things: I again created a brand new (Further-Options Teamsite-Template) site collection and this one neither react to Accept-Language-Header, Delve-Language Setting or MS Account Prefered-Language Settings. SPO delivers only content given by MS Account Display-Language ... but still without possibility to create Field/Column variants

Comment: Once you change your account profile language , what you call Delve language setting, Accept-Languages doesn't matter.  Don't change the MS Account Display Language after the profile language is set, and don't change language settings back and forth within a couple of minutes.  Changing the Display language sets up a delayed change to the profile language.  Any profile language change sets up a synchronization timer job propagating that change to each site, one at a time, which can take several minutes. Only change the profile and be patient. Or leave it blank and use the browser language.

Comment: Yes I know - thats why my comments delayed that way: I check with multiple hours between the changes.
The created site-collection-admin user for the new site did not had any settings at the beginning and I started with the Accept-Language header.
The online behavior is really frustrating: you never know if some things changing in background ... and if there are changes, you don´t know if you are in the current rollout group :/

Comment: Yes, frustrating. Disclaimer: I work for a company that makes a product that solves this, so I don't personally experience this frustration.